# Why do I get a FK constraint error when the PK value exists in the referenced table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to insert a record into a table with a Foreign Key Constraint. The constrained field is AccountID. I understand I can not insert records into the table if the value I'm inserting for AccountID does not exist in the table referenced by the constraint.

Below is an example of the insert statement I'm using:

```
INSERT INTO sometable (
AccountId
,TIdCode

)

VALUES (
'801143'
,2239754448

   )

go

select *
from sometable
where TIdCode = 2239754448
```

My question is why am I getting a FK constraint error when the primary key value reference exists in the table referenced by the constraint.

I'm aware of how to disable then re-enable the constraint. However, I would like to understand why I'm getting this error.

Comment: Is accountid an int or varchar column? Maybe try doing a select on the table that contains accountid using the value your trying to use as an FK reference. Maybe something like `SELECT * FROM Account WHERE AccountId = '801143'` and see if that returns a value.

Comment: In some way, shape, or form, your assumptions are incorrect - maybe the foreign key is actually defined on different columns; Or the data you think is present isn't actually there; Maybe there are additional whitespace characters that aren't obvious in the `AccountID` that *looks* like `801143`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the value was not in the table after all. I assumed the values from my production system were present in my test system. Thank you Damien_The _Unbeliever for asking a question that made me question my assumptions. Mr. Moose thank you as well for your insight.